# How to post to facebook page feed?

Tags: titanium

I am using Ti Studio 3.1.1 GA to build a native iOS app (6.1) integrated into facebook.
I am trying to post a story to one of my fan pages that I own.
The story is always written to "Recently posted by others" section in facebook than using the facebook page id.

```
fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/accounts', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        fb.permissions = ['publish_stream', 'read_stream','manage_pages'];
        fb.authorize();

        access_tokens = JSON.parse(e.result);

        for (var i = 0; i < fanpages.length; i++) {
            for ( var j=0; j < access_tokens.data.length; j++) {
                if (fanpages[i].id === access_tokens.data[j].id){
                var data = {
                link: "http://www.example.co/index.html",
                picture: returnedData[0].image,                             };
            fb.requestWithGraphPath(fanpages[i].id + '/feed' ,  data,     'POST',showRequestResult);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

}
```

If instead of 'link' above, if I have 'message' in the {data} section then it writes to the fanpage as page id but if I use 'link' then it writes in the 'Recent story by others' section...
When i tested the above functionality using the Tools->Graph API explorer from http://developers.facebook.com, by using the page id token then the story gets posted to the facebook fanpage as page id.
I am not sure how we can pass the page access token if its 'link'. Thought the above code is already passing the page access token....
Anyone has implemented or any ideas on how to go further?
Thanks in advance,
Regards, KP

Answer (score 1):

have you tried just using the feed dialog API call?

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook-method-dialog

Sample from Appcelerator Documentation

```
var data = {
    link : "http://www.appcelerator.com",
    name : "Appcelerator Titanium Mobile",
    message : "Checkout this cool open source project for creating mobile apps",
    caption : "Appcelerator Titanium Mobile",
    picture : "http://developer.appcelerator.com/assets/img/DEV_titmobile_image.png",
    description : "You've got the ideas, now you've got the power. Titanium translates " +
                  "your hard won web skills into native applications..."
};
fb.dialog("feed", data, function(e) {
    if(e.success && e.result) {
        alert("Success! New Post ID: " + e.result);
    } else {
        if(e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("User canceled dialog.");
        }
    }
});
```